# Eigenvectors of a Matrix as Vectors consisting of Weights of Linear Combinations of Column Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The way I understand the concept of the eigenvectors of a $n$ x $n$ matrix $A$ is from the effect of $A$ on the vectors: If $\mathbf{b}$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then the only effect of $A$ on $\mathbf{b}$ is stretching.

I am looking for another viewpoint, if exists, from the linear combination definition of matrix-vector multiplication: the entries of $\mathbf{b}$ are the weights of the column vectors of $A$ in their combination. Thus, we see that *using the entries of an eigenvector of a matrix as weights in a linear combination of the column vectors of that matrix results in a vector that is a scaling version of the vector consisting of the weights*. **What is the significance of this observation, if any?**

Comment: Frankly, I think both of these motivations miss an essential motivation for the concept of eigenvectors: what are the fixed lines of a linear transformation?

Comment: @amd If I understand correctly, the fixed lines are the lines along the eigenvectors. I still don't see much from this. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: I don’t really see that there’s much insight into the nature of eigenvectors to be gained from the linear combination of columns view, but it can help you find eigenvectors by inspection/trial-and-error. For artificial problems in homework sets and on exams, that can be a useful skill.

Comment: do you knwo 3blue1brown playlist of linear algebra? You'd like it! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNk_zzaMoSs&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab